# How to use CacheBuiler from Guava as a ConcurrentLRUCache

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, guava, google-guava-cache

so im using CacheBuilder by Guava as a ConcurrentLRUCache meaning this cache is thread safe and has LRU properties, see [CacheBuilder Guava Docs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html).

My assumption is when multiple threads are launched concurrently having the same key, a CyclicBarrier is used for this, then one thread will put() into the cache while the others wait. After that the remaining threads will see that a value is already in the cache and not put() into the cache.

This does not hold for the code below because each thread creates a new Object() and puts it into the cache. Verify by running the test and looking at the consol to see that different objects are created each time.

- Is there anything inherently wrong with the way I'm using the
  CacheBuilder?
- Is there better methods I can use?
- Is there a library I can use?

Please and thanks!

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;

public class GuavaLRUCacheTest {
    private Cache<String, Object> concurrentLRUCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).concurrencyLevel(1).build();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // The gate size is set based on the (number of threads to run) + (1 for the current thread).
        CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(4);

        // Same key is used for all threads
        ConcurrentLRUTestThread t1 = new ConcurrentLRUTestThread(gate, "key1");
        ConcurrentLRUTestThread t2 = new ConcurrentLRUTestThread(gate, "key1");
        ConcurrentLRUTestThread t3 = new ConcurrentLRUTestThread(gate, "key1");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        // Open the gate on all threads.
        gate.await();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }

    class ConcurrentLRUTestThread extends Thread {
        private CyclicBarrier gate;
        private String key;
        public ConcurrentLRUTestThread(CyclicBarrier gate, String key) {
            this.gate = gate;
            this.key = key;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                gate.await();
                if (concurrentLRUCache.getIfPresent(key) == null) {
                    System.out.println(">>>>> "+ System.nanoTime() +" - "+Thread.currentThread().getId() + " before put " + concurrentLRUCache.getIfPresent(key));
                    concurrentLRUCache.put(key, new Object());
                    System.out.println(">>>>> "+ System.nanoTime() +" - "+Thread.currentThread().getId() + " after put " + concurrentLRUCache.getIfPresent(key));
                } else{
                    System.out.println(">>>>> "+ System.nanoTime() +" - "+Thread.currentThread().getId() + " else " + concurrentLRUCache.getIfPresent(key));
                }  
            } catch (Throwable x) {
                System.out.println(">>>>> "+ System.currentTimeMillis() +" - "+Thread.currentThread().getId() + " ConcurrentLRUTestThread exception");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use `LoadingCache`, or at least `get(key, callable)`. If you are on JDK8 you might consider my [rewrite](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine).

Comment: You have no synchronization between `getIfPresent` and `put`, so all the threads can easily enter the first `if` branch, while none of them invoked `put`, and then each of them will perform `put`.

Answer (score 3):

You're first call `cache.getIfPresent` and then try to call `cache.put`. This will not work because this wasn't done as single atomic action. Multiple threads can see absence of value in the cache which will result in several `cache.put` calls. Straightforward way to fix this would be to make a critical section which includes check and action. Then only one thread will see absence of value in the cache. Fortunately `Cache` already contains method which does the thing: `Cache.get(key, valueLoader)`. Just use it to retrieve value:

```
    public class GuavaLRUCacheTest {

    private Cache concurrentLRUCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).concurrencyLevel(1).build();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // The gate size is set based on the (number of threads to run) + (1 for the current thread).
        CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(4);

        // Same key is used for all threads
        ConcurrentLRUTestThread t1 = new ConcurrentLRUTestThread(gate, "key1");
        ConcurrentLRUTestThread t2 = new ConcurrentLRUTestThread(gate, "key1");
        ConcurrentLRUTestThread t3 = new ConcurrentLRUTestThread(gate, "key1");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        // Open the gate on all threads.
        gate.await();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }

    class ConcurrentLRUTestThread extends Thread {
        private CyclicBarrier gate;
        private String key;
        public ConcurrentLRUTestThread(CyclicBarrier gate, String key) {
            this.gate = gate;
            this.key = key;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                gate.await();
                concurrentLRUCache.get(key, Object::new);
            } catch (Throwable x) {
                System.out.println(">>>>> "+ System.currentTimeMillis() +" - "+Thread.currentThread().getId() + " ConcurrentLRUTestThread exception");
            }
        }
    }
}
```